# c++ Sort Vector based on distance to external Point

Tags: c++, sorting

I was wondering if there is a nice way to sort a vector based on some external value.  For instance, I have a vector of k nearest neighbors to a point.  I want to sort this vector based on their distance to the query point.  The query point is not included in the results, and std::sort allows you to define a comparison function for two elements in the vector (rather than each element vs a fixed point).  Is there any pre-built method to do this sort of sort?  Or would I need to build my own custom sorting algorithm?  Thanks

Comment: The straightforward solution is to use a custom comparison function object with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (as presented in the answers below). But this can become quite wasteful, since it'll (potentially) calculate the same distances multiple times. If that is an issue for you, you might have to pre-calculate the distances, or do some form of caching of the calculated distances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have some class `Point` and the point you want to sort against is

```
Point p
```

Also assume that `points` is defined as

```
std::vector<Point> points;
```

and you had some function `dist` that took 2 `Point` and returned the distance (e.g. Euclidean distance) like

```
double dist(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    // compute Euclidean distance or whatever
}
```

Then you can use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a lambda function

```
std::sort(begin(points),
          end(points),
          [p](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs){ return dist(p, lhs) < dist(p, rhs); });
```

**Edit**
If you do not have C++11 access, you need to define a functor

```
struct DistanceFunc
{
    DistanceFunc(const Point& _p) : p(_p) {}

    bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) const
    {
        return dist(p, lhs) < dist(p, rhs);
    }

private:
    Point p;
};
```

Then you can sort in a similar way

```
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), DistanceFunc(p));
```

Comment: Is there a method you can think of without Lambdas?  I am restricted to using a compiler that doesn't have full c++11 support yet.

Comment: @armstrhu: you could make a function object to do the same thing as the lambda.

Comment: But I wont be able to capture the query point and still match the parameter template right?

Comment: You can capture the point `p` by passing it as a constructor argument to the function object. Not sure what you mean about "match the parameter template".

Comment: I guess what I meant is that sort is going to call f(Point lhs,Point rhs), so adding the query point wouldn't match that.  Construction the object with the query point should do it.  Thanks!

Comment: @armstrhu: CoryKramer's edit is exactly what I was referring to. So there you go.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a different sorting algorithm. `std::sort` works perfectly fine with user-provided orders.

The only problem here seems to be your definition. It still is easy, use a lambda : `[X] (Point A, Point B) { return distance(A,X) < distance(B,X); }`

Answer (score 0):

you could just use the method you're talking about with two points from the vector (including your external point inside the vector) and then make sure to pop_front/erase when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function object:

```
struct closer : public binary_function<point, point, bool>
{
  closer(point np):p(np)
  {}

  point p;

  bool operator()(point x, point y) { return dist(x,p) < dist(y,p); }
};

sort(V.begin(), V.end(), closer(P));
```